# Why aren't any slimes spawning in my slime farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I dug a large room to specifications, 3 blocks tall and 16 blocks wide as well as long. I dug it at 10 levels above bedrock, in a location {(-240, 0) -> (-224, 16)} specified by [this](http://mcslimes.appspot.com/) slime finder app. I am definitely more than 24 blocks away and less than 32 away from the spawn room, as specified by the wiki [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime#Spawning).

Yet, no slimes. I have been sitting in my location patiently listening for the moist slapping sounds of slime. I have gone in to the room every time I heard a phantom slap but still nothing.

Am I just being dumb somehow or do the minecraft lords just hate me?

If it helps/anyone cares here's my seed: 6405460532872068998

Comment: Are slimes still ludicrously rare? I saw them twice in what must have been a day of gametime, but that was last year before the full release

Comment: Most probably OP had no sky access or the chunk wasnt a slime chunk afterall

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you ever seen a slime in your farm?  If answer is no, good chance you got something wrong somewhere in your calculations.

If you have seen a slime, then very likely there are just too many other places for MOBS to spawn in the 150x150 region around you, that fill up all the MOB slots.  Time to break out the torches, and start lighting everything around you.

What I have found best, is to just let it sit for a long time while I do something else in the region, then revisit occasionally.  This helps, because slimes spawn more slowly than other MOBS, *but* they do not despawn like other MOBS, so if you have a good slime spawning region, they will continuously accumulate....  It can get crazy.

Comment: Nope, I haven't seen a single slime. Come to think of it, I actually do recall hearing zombie/skeleton sounds around the area. That might be it! Thank you!

Comment: I stumbled across an area that spawns slimes, and revisit often, but I've only found slimes there about 3 times out of probably a hundred or more visits over a month or so.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime#Spawning):

> Slimes spawn only 1/10th as often as other hostile mobs, so they can be hard to find.

So, according to the information you have given, you are doing everything correctly, and Notch is simply not smiling down upon you.  One thing that may increase you luck is lighting up the slime farm in some manner.  Slimes do not have lighting restrictions so preventing *other* mobs from spawning will increase the chances of a successful slime spawn.

Comment: I will try out lighting up the entire area around me and see if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should dig down a little deeper. I like slime farms to be about blocks 4 above bedrock. See if that helps.

Comment: They spawn from 0-40 equally.

Answer (score -2):

You should light up the area like everyone is saying and try to keep a 150x150 area around your farm quarantined.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend that you add a ton of torches and then just do something else. Visit the slime farm every 5 Minecraft days.

Comment: Why every 5 days?

Comment: Why not? Funny :)